# How to create get or create object from serializer data

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm passing two serializer with one view.
On creating object I want to first create CaseId object which is why I'm poping out CaseObject from validated data.

I want to get or create an object with the given data. Because I want to pass that to the CaseMessage object as a reference.

**Case Id Model**

```
class CaseId(models.Model):
    app_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    source_ref = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="auto generated with app_id,date,shot_uuid", null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(),
    external_id = models.IntegerField(default=0),
    group_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    case_tags = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
    case_url = models.SlugField(null= True, blank=True)
```

**Case Message Model**

```
class CaseMessage(models.Model):
    caseid = models.ForeignKey(CaseId, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="case_message")
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='case_message_parent', null=True, blank=True)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    source_ref = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    plain_body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**CaseId Serializer**

```
class CaseIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CaseId
        exclude = ('ref_id',)
```

**CaseMessageSeriaizer**

```
class CaseMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    case_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    case_object = CaseIdSerializer(required=False)
    message_type = ChoicesFieldSerializer(choices=CaseMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE)
    body_format = ChoicesFieldSerializer(choices=CaseMessage.BODY_FORMAT)

    class Meta:
        model = CaseMessage
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1

    def create(self, validated_data):
        raw_case_object = validated_data.pop('case_object', None)

        # Not Getting or creating object with the given data.
        case = CaseId.objects.get_or_create(**raw_case_object)

        case_message = CaseMessage(**validated_data)
        case_message.caseid = case
        case_message.save()

        if not CaseAudience.objects.filter(case_id=case).exists():
            case_audiance = CaseAudience(
            case_id = case, 
            source_message = case_message,
            )
            case_audiance.save()

        return validated_data
```

The Errors are as follows:

[image]

Console Error where it shows the item was OrderDict (I highlighted it on top corner):
[image]

Comment: What is the `case_object` that you get can you show its value

Comment: it show as "collections.OrderedDict"

Comment: Update question with model and the response of `case_object`